# Ensuring Redirects on a Proxied Server work correctly

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, proxypass

So I am currently trying to understand what configuration is a good idea for an nginx proxy. I am a bit stuck on the following two options:

- `proxy_set_header Host $host;`
- `proxy_redirect default;` (which is the default anyway and thus superflous)

If I understand it correctly then they both seem to target the same goal: ensuring that redirect work correctly. Setting the header variable `Host` to `$host` (which is the name of the nginx server, while the default (`$proxy_host`) is the name of the proxy server), ensures that the proxy server "views itself as `$host`" and thus links paths of type `/some/sub/path` to resources at `$host/some/sub/path` instead of `$proxy_host/some/sub/path`.

But this seems to be the purpose `proxy_redirect` is for as well. So I am not sure what to make of this. Maybe I am not really understanding those parameters quite right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The role for `Host` header is for the upstream server to select the correct virtual host for serving the site. Also, the application uses it to determine that visitor connects to correct domain.

The `proxy_redirect` is used to modify `Location` / `Refresh` fields in the responses the upstream server sends back to visitors.

So, these two features complement each other. The `Host` header is used to route request, while `proxy_redirect` is used to modify response.

Comment: So the host has more of a DNS type of role (selecting the right server to route the request to), while the proxy_redirect actually does the link fixing?

Comment: Yes, virtual hosts are connected to DNS in a way. `proxy_redirect` does not do link fixing for links in HTML code. It only alters HTTP headers for `3xx` redirect responses, changing the `Location` header appropriately.